# getting attributes of all the parent in xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have following xml structure

```
<comp name = "a">
    <subcomp1 name = "a1">
        <subcomp2 name = "a2"/>
    </subcomp1>
    <subcomp3 name="a3/>
</comp>
```

If I try the following syntax,

```
<xsl:value-of select="@name" />
```

gives attribute value of name when I am in perticular tag. ie when I am at

```
<comp> @name = a, at<subcomp2> it is a2
```

But I want to get all the attribute value including the parents. ie when I am at

```
<subcomp2> I want value a->a1->a2
<subcomp1> a->a1
<subcomp3> a->a3

<xsl:value-of select="..\@name" />
```

gives only one parent above. So please let me know the solution for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you want is `ancestor-or-self::*/@name`

If you are using XSLT 2.0, then `xsl:value-of` returns all matching attributes, so you can just do this to list them, for example

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor-or-self::*/@name" separator="-" />
```

However, in XSLT 1.0, `xsl:value-of` will only return the value of the first one. So, you can use `xsl:for-each` instead

```
<xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*/@name">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">-</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Or maybe this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">-</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
</xsl:for-each>
```